# Referenciar una llave primaria compuesta en otra tabla Como foránea compuesta

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Resulta que estoy desarrollando un ejercicio de un libro de gestión de bases de datos ya que soy nuevo en esto y pues para poder darme a entender voy a mostrar el ejercicio y el grafo relacional de la bases de datos:

[image: Enunciado ejercicio]

[image: Grafo Relacional de la base de datos]

Bien pues estoy desarrollando la primera parte de la actividad en MySql Workbech y pues necesito referenciar la llave primaria compuesta de la tabla `equipo` a la tabla `partido` y que `elocal y evisitante` sean la llave primaria de dicha tabla, que se actualizaran dependiendo de los equipos que vayan a jugar en la tabla equipo. A continuación escribo lo que yo he desarrollado:

```
CREATE DATABASE liga;
    USE liga;
    CREATE TABLE jugadores (
    id_jugador INTEGER(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    dni INTEGER(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellido VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    equipo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    edad INTEGER(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    fecha_alta DATE
    );
    CREATE TABLE equipo(
    id_equipo INTEGER(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ciudad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    puntos INTEGER(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    id_capitan INTEGER(4) UNSIGNED UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_equipo, nombre)
    );
    CREATE TABLE partido(
    id_equipo INTEGER(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    elocal VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    evisitante VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (elocal, evisitante),
    CONSTRAINT fk_equipo_partido FOREIGN KEY (elocal, evisitante) references equipo (id_equipo, nombre)
    );
```

Sin embargo yo intenté seguir un ejemplo que plantea el libro el cuál es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo entiendo que debería colocarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
FOREIGN KEY (id_equipo, nombre) references equipo (id_equipo, nombre)
```

pero si notan la captura de pantalla del ejemplo del libro, no lo plantearon así si no más bien como bien dice ahí: "Incluyendo una clave ajena que referencia al campo de la otra tabla" en resumidas cuentas eso es lo que yo necesito Incluir las claves ajenas "`elocal y evisitante`" que referencien los campos "`id_equipo y nombre`" de la tabla `equipo` y que además los campos `elocal y evisitante` sean la llave primaria de la tabla `partido` tal y como se indica en el grafo relacional.

Disculpen la molestia es que soy nuevo en esto y espero me halla logrado dar a entender.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer ya pude crearla exitosamente en Workbench a continuación dejo el código:

```
CREATE DATABASE liga;
    USE liga;
    CREATE TABLE jugadores (
    id_jugador INTEGER(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    dni INTEGER(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellido VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    equipo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    edad INTEGER(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    fecha_alta DATE
    );
    CREATE TABLE equipo(
    id_equipo INTEGER(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ciudad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    puntos INTEGER(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    id_capitan INTEGER(4) UNSIGNED UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_equipo, nombre)
    );
    CREATE TABLE partido(
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    elocal VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    evisitante VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    id_equipo INTEGER(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (elocal, evisitante),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_equipo, elocal) REFERENCES equipo(id_equipo, nombre),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_equipo, evisitante) REFERENCES equipo(id_equipo, nombre)
    );
```

A pesar de que nadie  respondió, la dejo acá por si alguien la puede llegar a necesitar.